# Invalid use of incomplete type error in c

Tags: c

I know that this question already got answered a lot but I've read a lot of threads and I couldn't find a answer for me. 
I get the error

`invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct PackAnimalImplementation’
         if(animal->type != 0 && current == caravan)`

for the following code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "caravan.h"
#include "general.h"


#define COUNT_CARAVANS 5

/*
Basically our Node
*/
struct CaravanImplementation{
    int length;
    PackAnimal animal;
    struct CaravanImplementation* next;
};

Caravan head = (Caravan)malloc(sizeof(struct CaravanImplementation));

void add_pack_animal(Caravan caravan, PackAnimal animal)
{
    Caravan current = head;
    while(current != 0){
        if(animal->type != 0 && current == caravan)
        {
            current->animal = animal;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the struct I want to use, it's in the file pack_animal.cpp and got forward declared in the pack_animal.h file:

Forward Declaration:

```
typedef struct PackAnimalImplementation* PackAnimal;
```

Definition in cpp file:

```
struct PackAnimalImplementation {
    AnimalType type; //The AnimalType is an enum with 2 values: Horse and Camel
    const char *name;
    int max_speed;
    int load;
    Caravan caravan;
};
```

The caravan.h, pack_animal.h and pack_animal.cpp files don't have any issues. This is a school exercise and my teacher made them and told me they actually work. Would be glad if someone could help me.

Comment: A `cpp` file does not usually contain *C* code. Please ensure that you're not actually coding C++?!

Comment: the "declaration" in cpp file is the *definition* of the structure. It needs to go to a header, otherwise the type is incomplete in other files that need to access it.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Doesn't it go to a header? I included the .h file in the cpp file. Isn't this how it works? Sorry I am just a beginner and just really confused.

Comment: A C translation unit at compile time cannot see **anything** written in another translation unit. The preprocessor `#include`s work as if copy-pasting the contents of the given file as is at that position.

Comment: Ohh okay, now I understand. Thank you very much hope you have a great day!

Comment: @Samuel Happy new year!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't hide the definition of `PackAnimalImplementation` away in a .cpp file. Anything that wants to "do things" with objects of that type need to know what it looks like.

Move it to the header file, or engage in some PIMPL antics if you want to hide it all away (but then you're going to need to provide some accessor functions, and free ones at that if you're targeting C compatibility).

---

Further reading:

- [When can I use a forward declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/553682/560648)

Comment: Now I have a Segmentation fault but I think I made a mistake in the program, I will figure this out later. But why does the forward declaration work with other structs tho? I have never used it like you told me now.

Comment: @Samuel Whether a forward declaration is sufficient depends on usage.

Comment: Thank you very much, I think I understand it now and also everything works just fine!